# Bound TextBox Loop Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I bound a TextBox to the ViewModel.

I'm trying to use:
`string txt = vm.Example_Text;`

The same as:
`string txt = tbxExample.Text;`

---

**Problem**

Typing in the TextBox works fine.

But after typing, if I click out of the TextBox and to another control, the program crashes and throws the error `Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.`

---

Here's a source file of just the TextBox and ViewModel
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1hfnkmdckpwtms/TextBoxMVVM.zip?dl=0

---

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbxExample" 
         Text="{Binding Example_Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding Example_IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Padding="1, 1, 0, 0" 
         Margin="0,2,0,0"
         Width="100"
         Height="22"

         MaxLines="1" />
```

---

**ViewModel**

```
public string _Example_Text;

public string Example_Text
{
    get { return _Example_Text; }
    set
    {
        if (_Example_Text == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        Example_Text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Example_Text");
    }
}
```

The error in debug seem to highlight `set { }`;

Comment: @GrantWinney this should be the/an answer.

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks, it looks like it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, you used `Example_Text` instead of `_Example_Text`. That means a forever loop to set `Example_Text`

```
set
    {
        if (_Example_Text == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Example_Text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Example_Text");
    }
```

Comment: This was already answered in the comments by @Grant Winney

Comment: We have answered at the same time, 1 min ago. thanks for downvote

Comment: Grant answered 7 mins before you did

Comment: I didn't focus on the comment...

Comment: Agreed, it was probably a typo, so a comment was a fine response.  However, you (Grant) provided the answer in the comments first, providing the same answer in the comments provides no extra benefit.

Comment: Everyone has his own perspective. I saw a question with a silly problem, I write down right away the answer with a mood inside. You have right to downvote, I have right to write the answer to the question which hasn't yet a right answer.

Comment: It did have an answer already (the comment correctly answered OP's question), that's my point...

Comment: Yes, that's your point. You can downvote if you seem that's correct. Discussion finished here.

Comment: The comment solved the problem but I will mark this answer as accepted as it shows the full code and there is no other answer post.